# Travel from USA to India - Transit Visa requirement?

Tags: international-travel

I am traveling from seattle to bangalore via london airport.

Do i require transit visa, if my current US visa (h1b) expired?
I have valid canadian visitor visa, would that suffice or still i need to have transit visa for UK?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need a transit visa.

> **Exemptions**
>
> You don’t need a visa if you have one of the following:
>
> - a visa for ***Canada***, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (***this can be used for travel to any country***)

[Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no)

You can see what options I chose in the visa check flow to get that answer, please ensure that my choices were correct (especially the "will you need to leave the airport" one, as that slightly changes the outcome).

Comment: Thanks for answering the question...Have you personally experienced this situation?

Comment: No, Im British :)

Comment: today i spent my whole day talking to british airways people, but they gave me mixed and confused answers, i am planning to contact UK consulate in USA to make sure.

Comment: @ajaykumar be aware that neither the British Consulate nor any airline staff will give you a water tight legal answer, because its not their job to - they don't want to end up with liability for giving you the wrong advice.  But if you put your exact requirements and situation into the link I give above then thats pretty much rock solid.